# How to filter/search JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I need to search/filter JSON object based on the search value.

My JSON object as follows,

```
[
   {
      "No":"21",
      "Area":"Default",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"1108",
            "Area":"Davie",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"1107",
            "Area":"Ft. region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"1105",
            "Area":"Hollywood",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"17",
      "Area":"East",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"212",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"219",
            "Area":"region116",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"24",
      "Area":"East11",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"211",
            "Area":"region108",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"218",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"1102",
            "Area":"region999",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"25",
      "Area":"N25",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"213",
            "Area":"region110",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"220",
            "Area":"region117",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"15",
      "Area":"North",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"214",
            "Area":"region111",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"221",
            "Area":"region118",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"27",
      "Area":"ZRegion",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"1110",
            "Area":"region111",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"210",
            "Area":"Pacific Test",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As the example when the search key is **East** output result should be,because that node consists word called **East**

```
   {
      "No":"17",
      "Area":"East",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"212",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"219",
            "Area":"region116",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   }
```

As another example when the search key is **region109** following result I expecting. because each nodes consists **region109** word.

```
   {
      "No":"21",
      "Area":"Default",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"1107",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"17",
      "Area":"East",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"212",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   }
```

How can I do this.please help me.I simply tried following code,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputJson = "[\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"21\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"Default\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1108\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"Davie\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1107\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"Ft. region109\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1105\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"Hollywood\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"17\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"East\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"212\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region109\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"219\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region116\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"24\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"East11\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"211\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region108\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"218\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region109\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1102\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region999\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"25\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"N25\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"213\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region110\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"220\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region117\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"15\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"North\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"214\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region111\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"221\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region118\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"27\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"ZRegion\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1110\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region111\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"210\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"Pacific Test\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   }\r\n]";

    var jArrObject = JArray.Parse(inputJson);


    var items = jArrObject.SelectTokens("$.[?(@.Area=='Default')]");

    foreach (var item in items)
        Console.WriteLine(item);

}
```

but its not solved my problem, its just only try what I did

**Updated:**

I tried below code, its working,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputJson = "[\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"21\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"Default\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1108\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"Davie\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1107\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"Ft. region109\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1105\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"Hollywood\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"17\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"East\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"212\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region109\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"219\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region116\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"24\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"East11\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"211\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region108\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"218\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region109\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1102\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region999\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"25\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"N25\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"213\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region110\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"220\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region117\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"15\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"North\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"214\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region111\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"221\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region118\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"No\":\"27\",\r\n      \"Area\":\"ZRegion\",\r\n      \"Branches\":[\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"1110\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"region111\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         },\r\n         {\r\n  \"No\":\"210\",\r\n  \"Area\":\"Pacific Test\",\r\n  \"IsValid\":\"False\"\r\n         }\r\n      ]\r\n   }\r\n]";

    var jArrObject = JArray.Parse(inputJson);

    string searchKey = "Davie";
    var items = jArrObject.SelectTokens("$.[?(@..Area=='" + searchKey + "')]");

    foreach (var item in items)
        Console.WriteLine(item);

}
```

but when I pass the **Area** as parameter which returns all the nodes. as the example  when the Area = "Davie" out put was,

```
{
  "No": "21",
  "Area": "Default",
  "Branches": [
    {
      "No": "1108",
      "Area": "Davie",
      "IsValid": "False"
    },
    {
      "No": "1107",
      "Area": "Ft. region109",
      "IsValid": "False"
    },
    {
      "No": "1105",
      "Area": "Hollywood",
      "IsValid": "False"
    }
  ]
}
```

But expected output is, how to remove other two(1107,1105). how to get related node only

```
{
  "No": "21",
  "Area": "Default",
  "Branches": [
    {
      "No": "1108",
      "Area": "Davie",
      "IsValid": "False"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `var items = jArrObject.SelectTokens("$.[?(@..Area=='Default')]");`  Note double dots

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I tried like that. its shows all the content,as the example if `"Area": == "region110",` **region117** data also showing. how to hide it

Comment: @Brian Rogers please help me

Comment: `$.[?(@..Area=='" + searchKey + "')]` json path expression is selecting the root level nodes using `$.` and searching for Area under Branches node using `(@..Area='Devis')` expression. Once an area is matched under the branches node the root level Area node is selected which includes other branch nodes as well. Other option is to explicitly select Branch level nodes using `$..Branches[?(@.Area=='Davie')]`. Here you will get output only like `{
      "No": "1108",
      "Area": "Davie",
      "IsValid": "False"
    }`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I'm not claer sir,could u please give proper and tested answer for me. please sir

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I got the point, I tried your answer as `$..Branches[?(@.Area=='Davie')]`  but when the **search key = "Default"** root level not selecting. So no output displaying

Comment: Yes because `$..Branches[?(@.Area=='Davie')]` means that you are searching for Area under Branches node and not under root level nodes. Thats why I suggested to use two search expressions one for searching Area under root level nodes and other under Branches node

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood clear sir. Suppose when the search result match with both root and branch level. how to concatenate JSON output. and other problem is when I using the code as `jArrObject.SelectTokens("$..Branches[?(@.Area=='region109')]");` its only give branch level data only(`{
            "No":"212",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }`). but I also need to get its root data also `   {
      "No":"17",
      "Area":"East",
      "Branches":[

      ]
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Create class models for your Json objects:

```
public class Region
{
    public int No { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    public int No { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use:

```
var regions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Region[]>(inputJson);
```

Now, to get a subset, (`using System.Linq`):

```
var eastRegions = regions.Where(r => r.Area == "East");
```

If you need it converted back to Json:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eastRegions);
```

Comment: please check my updated question. I have another problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to search on Area field in your json which can exist either at root level or under branches. So you can do something like this:

```
var rootAreaItems = jArrObject.SelectTokens("$.[?(@.Area=='Default')]");
var branchAreaItems = jArrObject.SelectTokens("$..Branches[?(@.Area=='Davie')]");
```

Then print them.

Comment: please check my updated question. I think I updated my problem properly, as u said I need to get either root level or under branches. but need to only retrieve that search key consist node as my expected output example